# Android - String

Tags: java, android

Probably a noob question but, after some search I could not find the answer.

I've receive this String like the following one: "Distribui\u00e7\u00e3o Alimentar", and I want to set it as text of a `EditText`. How can I "replace" the \u00e7 and \u00e3o to "ç" and "ã"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to, it is a unicode char literal.

Comment: ohhh my bad, really really noob. I open the browser and saw all the unicode char on the json, thought that I had to "convert" them to show it on editText, tried now and it worked. Next time I'll try before ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[With the string replace function](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html)

`String newString = stringName.replaceAll("\u007", "c');`

`String newString2 = stringName.replaceAll("\u00e7", "a");`

and you could concatenate the two with the `concat` method